# Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Full Screening Scaling Problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

In my Adobe Air application, I have a room and my player that can walk around it. I set it so it automatically opens in fullscreen, however, when you exit fullscreen it doesn't scale anything, so it just shows you the edge of the room, where you can't see the player or anything else. How do I make it so that when you exit fullscreen, everything will scale down to the windowed version, and back again? This is in Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.

I tried scaling everything down by putting an If statement in an update function, that constantly checks if the window is full screened or not, and if not, it'll scale the x and y down by .5, and if full screened again, it'll scale it back up by 1. The player however changes position, and if I try to make the X equal it it just does it again if I move the player, so it doesn't work. I've also tried verticleCenter and horizontalCenter on both the player and room, it also doesn't work.

What I'm wondering is if there is a stage.autoScale line that can solve everything, or if I have to do it manually another way like I've tried.

Comment: You dont need to "constantly check if a windows is full screened or not".. There's an **[automatic event message sent when you enter/exit the FS mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FullScreenEvent.html)**. Try setting the stage's **[scale mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html)** for example: `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;`. Try the other options in the AS3 manual for what works best for your app.

Answer (score 0):

So you got 2 options here.

1. Check for fullscreen event and then in the listener function scale everything according to your logics. This will give you more control over the scaling and visual display of your components and graphics. You can find a working example for fullscreen event handling at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html
2. Allow FP to scale the stage according to the window size. This can be achieved by setting up stage.scale mode. There are couple options which you can find at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html. Use the one best suit for your application.

I would prefer using first method. Hope that make sense.